# OBIEE Migration

Tags: migration, obiee

I want to migrate OBIEE 12c from Windows 12R server to Windows 2016 Standard. Can any one help me out with the process.

Thank you

Hi

I want to migrate OBIEE 12c from Windows 12R server to Windows 2016 Standard.
I cannot directly upgrade Windows server,so migration is only possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a clean OBIEE 12c in the new server, and then export the BAR, RPD, Users, etc from the old OBIEE 12c.